# How to disable an option based on a specific value in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, disabled-input

When the stock value in the Product array is less than 0 or 1,
I want to disable that value in the options so that it cannot be selected.(disable =true)
And if product stock is greater than 0,
I want to be able to select that value.(disable =false)
What should I do?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Form, Button} from 'antd' 

const Products = [    
    { key: 1, value: "A", stock: 0 },
    { key: 2, value: "B", stock: 1  },
    { key: 3, value: "C", stock: 2 },
    { key: 4, value: "D", stock: 0  },
    { key: 5, value: "E", stock: 0 },
    { key: 6, value: "F", stock: 3  },
    { key: 7, value: "G", stock: 4 },    
]

function ProductPage() {

// States
const [product, setProduct] = useState(1) // initial value : 1

// Handlers
const productChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setProduct(event.currentTarget.value)
}


return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
        <div style={{textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem'}}>
            <h2>Product Soldout State</h2>
        </div>
        
        <Form>

            {/* DropZone */}
            <br />
            <br />
            <select onChange={productChangeHandler} value={product} >
                {Products.map(item => (
                    <option key={item.key} value={item.key} >{item.value}</option>
                ))}                    
            </select>
            <Button>Upload</Button>

        </Form>

    </div>
)
```

}

export default ProductPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `disabled` JSX property, which maps to the [`disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-disabled): `disabled={item.stock < 1}`

In context:

```
{Products.map(item => (
    <option key={item.key} value={item.key} disabled={item.stock < 1}>{item.value}</option>
))}
```

More minimal example:

```js
const options = [
    {value: 1, stock: 40, text: "Plenty"},
    {value: 2, stock: 1, text: "Just enough"},
    {vlaue: 3, stock: 0, text: "None"},
];
const Example = () => {
    return <select>
        {options.map((option) => (
            <option value={option.value} disabled={option.stock < 1}>{option.text}</option>
        ))}
    </select>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```